# How to query on tracked field data?

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

I would like to know how I can query on tracked fields in all objects?

I have org with 50 objects that have tracked fields. Now I wanted to know how much data used as tracking history for particular Object/ Field.

eg: Test object has 10 fields that are tracked. The lead object has 5 fields and the Account object have 20.
I need a summary of that tracking history for all 3 objects, and in-depth like how much data there as history tracking for xyz field on Test obj, and so on.

So that way I can see which fields are changing frequently, and how often. also to get a good estimate in terms of the amount of space needed to retrieve all that "Field History Data" locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each field history object is distinct, so there's no global table you can query from. For example, LeadHistory is for the Lead object, and Test__History is for the Test__c object. You would need to run individual reports/queries to get the information you're looking for.